# Projective Module equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, projective-module

I'm trying to prove that given an $A-module$: $P$

> The functor $Hom(P,-)$ is exact $\implies$ $\exists Q (A-module): P\oplus Q$ is free

Can anyone guide me with some hints? It's the first time I'm seeing all of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There exists a free module $F$ and a surjection $p:F\rightarrow P$, you have the exact sequence $0\rightarrow Ker(p)\rightarrow F\rightarrow P\rightarrow 0$, thus the sequence $0\rightarrow Hom(P,Ker(p))\rightarrow Hom(P,F)\rightarrow Hom(P,P)\rightarrow 0$ is exact, thus the morphism $Hom(P,F)\rightarrow Hom(P,P)$ is surjective. We deduce that there exists a morphism $h:P\rightarrow F$ such that $p\circ h=Id_P$, you can write $F=h(P)\oplus ker(p)$ and $h(P)\simeq P$.

Comment: You can take $F$ to be the free module generated by $\{e_x,x\in P\}$ and $p$ defined by $p(e_x)=x$.

Comment: Setting $F = \oplus_{s \in P}A$ and $(a_s) \rightarrow \sum a_ss$ would do it right?

Comment: Yes, but you have to take finitely many $s$ in $(a_s)$ btw who downvoted?

Comment: Yeah, by definition there are only finitely many $a_s \neq 0$. I didn't down vote, I appreciate your answer and I am trying to understand it

Comment: Would you mind helping me out with two more equivalences?